# GML Simple Feature compliance test

Tags: gml, standards, testing, compliance

I'm in the process of defining a GML schema from a database schema, the idea is for it to be [GML simple feature compliant](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=42729). However I can't find a way to confirm this compliance other than reading the spec and manually checking. I'd feel happier if there was an automated tool I could pass the schema to which could check all was well. The existance of this sort of tool is hinted at in the spec (Appendix A) but I can't find one.

Does anyone know of such a tool?

Answer (score 1):

http://xml.coverpages.org/OGC-ComplianceTests.html mentions *"the TEAM Engine from http://sourceforge.net/projects/teamengine/ to test their implementations of the OGC's OpenGIS implementation specifications in the developers' own environments."*, but i've never tried that myself.

Comment: I think this checks that a provided test data set is encoded as GML SF0/1 rather than checking the schema